# jQuery code not executing in Angularjs controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have the following Angularjs controller that loads a JSON file and adds it to the scope so I can use it in the view.  I then have some jQuery code but this code is never getting executed.  I thought by placing the code in `$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {` it would wait for the page to load but I think that's not the case.  Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

```
myApp.controller('pageController', function($scope) {

$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
});

$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    //This event never gets fired
    $(".more").hover(function(e) {
        alert('here');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getJSON from jQuery happens outside the 'angular' world and needs to be wrapped in an `scope.$apply`

Try the following:

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
    $scope.apply(function () {
        $scope.data = data;
        //This event never gets fired
        $(".more").hover(function(e) {
            alert('here');
        });
    });      

});
```

I would recommend to use `$http` or `$resource` service from angular. If you use them, you do not need the call `$apply` anymore